# Cómo guardar en un Array resultados de un consulta en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, array

tengo el siguiente `query` en **MySQL**.

```
$select =" SELECT concat(colonia, ', ', calle, ' ', y_calle, ' ', no_exterior, ' ', no_interior) as direccion FROM scpd_incidencia WHERE colonia='EXTREMADURA INSURGENTES' ";
```

El cual arroja resultados:
[image: Resultados]

Quiero saber si los resultados del `concat` **direccion** se pueden guardar en un array, he hecho lo siguiente:

```
$dir = array();
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $dir[] = $row['direccion'];
}
echo $dir[0];
```

pero eso solo me arroja un resultado, lo que me guataria es que se mostrara asi:

```
$dir=['direccion1','direccion2', 'direccion3', etc...]
```

Hay manera de lograrlo??

Comment: Podrías utilizar el método [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) o [split](http://php.net/manual/es/function.split.php) de PHP para realizar eso :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema con lo que estas haciendo es que estas guardando en la misma posición de tu arreglo, así deberia de funcionar:

```
$dir = array();
$cont = 0;
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $dir[$cont] = $row['direccion'];
   $cont++;
}
```

Ahora ya tienes todo en tu arreglo $dir y para acceder a cada elemento tienes que recorrer tu arreglo.

```
foreach ($dir as $valor) {
    echo $valor;
}
```

Comment: Hola @M. Gress ya probé tu código, sin embargo sigue guardo el resultado en la misma posición, es decir solo imprime el resultado que le mandes en el `echo $dir[0];`, no todos los resultados.

Comment: @Artes He ,modificado mi respuesta.

Comment: ha resultado !!, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución podría ser:

```
for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);

print_r($set);
```

[mysqli-result](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)